# How to use HTML DOM using npm test (CLI)

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, npm, mocha.js

I am trying to find a way to run `npm test` using **mocha** over a `HTML DOM`. In this case, I am using the **global** `document` to retrieve a `table` out of the `DOM`. However, when I run `npm test` I get something like the error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at /home/luiz/Projects/linguist-unknown/src/scripts/ling-loader.js:92:61
at extFunc (/home/luiz/Projects/linguist-unknown/src/scripts/ling-loader.js:49:11)
at Array.every (native)
at Utilities.tryMatchUrlExtension (/home/luiz/Projects/linguist-unknown/src/scripts/ling-loader.js:60:25)
at Utilities.<anonymous> (/home/luiz/Projects/linguist-unknown/src/scripts/ling-loader.js:90:16)
at xhr.onload (/home/luiz/Projects/linguist-unknown/src/scripts/ling-loader.js:24:11)
at dispatchEvent (/home/luiz/Projects/linguist-unknown/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
at setState (/home/luiz/Projects/linguist-unknown/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:614:14)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/luiz/Projects/linguist-unknown/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:447:13)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  1) should refresh table


16 passing (3s)
1 failing

1) Loader Utilities should refresh table:
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I understand that the `document` is `undefined` and that I need to, somehow, create one myself, however, I believe that my main problems are:

1. My first time using `npm` and `mocha` and I cannot find anything related to it in their documentation.
2. Mostly, all problems people have regarding that are related to webbrowsers *// I am using CLI, it will be tested with Travis on Github*
3. In my code below you'll see that I solved a similar problem with `XMLHttpRequest`. However, I just can't figure out the best approach for  including the `document` variable properly into my tests.

Thus, pardon me asking that shall this answer be already there on **stackoverflow**

My code is the following:

*test-utilities.js*

```
...
global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
global.jsyaml = require('../src/scripts-min/js-yaml.min.js');
global.LinguistHighlighter = require('../src/scripts/ling-highlighter.js').LinguistHighlighter;
var LinguistLoader = require('../src/scripts/ling-loader.js').LinguistLoader;
describe('Loader', function () {
  var utilities = new LinguistLoader.Utilities();
  it('should refresh table', function(done) {
    var location = {
      hostname: "github.com",
      href: "https://github.com/github-aux/linguist-unknown/blob/chrome/examples/Brain/human_jump.brain",
      pathname: "/github-aux/linguist-unknown/blob/chrome/examples/Brain/human_jump.brain"
    };

    // check if it is not breaking
    utilities.refresh(location, function(langObj, table){
      done();
    });
  });
});
...
```

*utilities.js*:

```
...
Utilities.prototype.refresh = function(location, callback) {
  var new_url = location.href;

  if (new_url === current_url || !this.isGithub(location)) {
    return;
  }

  current_url = new_url;
  if (linguistObj === null) {
    linguistObj = {
      path: this.getPossibleFilepath(location)
    };
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    var downloadHelper = new DownloadHelper();
    downloadHelper.load(linguistObj.path, function(objs){
      this.tryMatchUrlExtension(current_url, objs, function(langObj){
        var table = document.getElementsByClassName("blob-wrapper")[0]
                          .getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
        new LinguistHighlighter.Highlighter(langObj).draw(table);

        // callback for tests purposes only
        if (callback) {
          callback(langObj, table);
        }
      });
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this), 100);
};
...
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: CLI doesn't have DOM, you have to run your DOM test in browsers. You can use selenium(http://www.seleniumhq.org/) with mocha to do the test. There are also some commercial tools like sauce labs and browserstack. For more details, refer to this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing and selenium's documentation.

Comment: Hi @YiKai, thanks for your answer, Selenium is indeed a great tool to help me with that, however, I found a solution 100% using CLI with [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)!

Comment: Yeah it seems to be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very good tool: [JSDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom). Its goal is to emulate a subset of a web browser, such as the `DOM`. With that, I could implement my `test-utilities.js` file without even touching my `utilities.js` file, which is pretty much what I wanted.

Here goes the resolution of the file `test-utilities.js`

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
global.jsyaml = require('../src/scripts-min/js-yaml.min.js');
global.LinguistHighlighter = require('../src/scripts/ling-highlighter.js').LinguistHighlighter;
var LinguistLoader = require('../src/scripts/ling-loader.js').LinguistLoader;

describe('Loader', function () {
  var utilities = new LinguistLoader.Utilities();
  
  it('should refresh the code table', function(done) {
    // Download the HTML string and parse it to JSDOM
    JSDOM.fromURL("https://github.com/github-aux/linguist-unknown/blob/chrome/examples/Brain/human_jump.brain").then(dom => {

    // JSDOM does not support 'innerText' and that is why I am creating this property for all objects. 
    var o = Object.prototype;
    Object.defineProperty(o, "innerText", {
      get: function jaca() {
        if (this.innerHTML === undefined)
          return "";
        return this.innerHTML;
      }
    });

    var location = {
      hostname: "github.com",
      href: "https://github.com/github-aux/linguist-unknown/blob/chrome/examples/Brain/human_jump.brain",
      pathname: "/github-aux/linguist-unknown/blob/chrome/examples/Brain/human_jump.brain"
    };

    // check if it is not breaking
    utilities.refresh(location, function(langObj, table) {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

That is working properly now! I hope it helps anyone! :D